# Что не так с моей рекурсией?

Tags: php, рекурсия

Всем привет! Написал такую рекурсию:

```
private function getFreeInterval(array $intervals, array $appointments)
    {
        $result = [];

        if (empty($appointments)) return $result;

        $value = array_shift($appointments);
        list($startTime, $endTime) = explode('-',$value);

        foreach ( $intervals as $key => $interval ) {
            list($start, $end) = explode('-', $interval);

            if ($startTime >= $start && $endTime <= $end) {
                if ($startTime > $start) {
                    $str = "{$start}-{$startTime}";
                    $result[] = $str;
                }
                if ($endTime < $end) {
                    $str = "{$endTime}-{$end}";
                    $result[] = $str;
                }

            } else {
                $result[] = $interval;
            }
        }

         return array_merge($result,$this->getFreeInterval($result,$appointments));
    }
```

Вот как я ее вызываю `$this->getInterval($intervals, $t);`

В intervals у меня вот что: `["02:00:00","20:30:00"]`
В $t вот что:

```
[
  "08:00:00-09:15:00",
  "09:15:00-10:30:00",
  "15:15:00-16:30:00",
  "12:15:00-13:30:00",
  "03:15:00-04:30:00",
  "05:15:00-06:30:00"
]
```

В результате мне нужно вот что:

```
array:6 [
  0 => "02:00:00-03:15:00"
  1 => "04:30:00-05:15:00"
  2 => "06:30:00-08:00:00"
  3 => "10:30:00-12:15:00"
  4 => "13:30:00-15:15:00"
  5 => "16:30:00-20:30:00"
]
```

Но она у меня вот что выводит:

```
array:22 [
  0 => "02:00:00-08:00:00"
  1 => "09:15:00-20:30:00"
  2 => "02:00:00-08:00:00"
  3 => "10:30:00-20:30:00"
  4 => "02:00:00-08:00:00"
  5 => "10:30:00-15:15:00"
  6 => "16:30:00-20:30:00"
  7 => "02:00:00-08:00:00"
  8 => "10:30:00-12:15:00"
  9 => "13:30:00-15:15:00"
  10 => "16:30:00-20:30:00"
  11 => "02:00:00-03:15:00"
  12 => "04:30:00-08:00:00"
  13 => "10:30:00-12:15:00"
  14 => "13:30:00-15:15:00"
  15 => "16:30:00-20:30:00"
  16 => "02:00:00-03:15:00"
  17 => "04:30:00-05:15:00"
  18 => "06:30:00-08:00:00"
  19 => "10:30:00-12:15:00"
  20 => "13:30:00-15:15:00"
  21 => "16:30:00-20:30:00"
]
```

Если я уберу в последнем `return'e array_merge` и оставлю только `$this->getFreeInterval($result,$appointments, $item);`, то она мне дает null, а если я после `$this->getFreeInterval($result,$appointments, $item)` поставлю `dd($result);` то она мне дает результат который мне нужен. Но как мне вернуть этот результат?

Почему рекурсия не так работает как нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```
<?php
$intervals = ["02:00:00","20:30:00"];
$appointments = [
  "08:00:00-09:15:00",
  "09:15:00-10:30:00",
  "15:15:00-16:30:00",
  "12:15:00-13:30:00",
  "03:15:00-04:30:00",
  "05:15:00-06:30:00"
];

function getFreeIntervals($intervals, $appointments)
{
    if (empty($appointments)) {
        return $intervals;
    }
    
    $result = [];
    
    usort($appointments, "date_sort");
    [$startWorkingTime, $endWorkingTime] = $intervals;

    foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {
        [$startAppointmentTime, $endAppointmentTime] = \explode('-', $appointment);
        if ($startAppointmentTime !== $startWorkingTime) {
            $result[] = $startWorkingTime . '-' . $startAppointmentTime;
            
            $startWorkingTime = $endAppointmentTime;
        }
        
        if ($startAppointmentTime === $startWorkingTime) {
            $startWorkingTime = $endAppointmentTime;
        }
    }
    
    if ($endAppointmentTime !== $endWorkingTime) {
        $result[] = $endAppointmentTime . '-' . $endWorkingTime;
    }
    
    return $result;
}

function date_sort($a, $b) {
    $a = \explode('-', $a)[0];
    $b = \explode('-', $b)[0];
    return \strtotime($a) - \strtotime($b);
}

$result = getFreeIntervals($intervals, $appointments);

print_r($result);
```